# I am getting error while running my dockerfile using docker-compose in nextjs13 when I run yarn build

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I just want to create production build file for my nextjs using DockerFile and COmpose FIle and I am getting error  'build not found'
This is the DockerFile-

```
FROM node:18
                                                  
WORKDIR /app
  
COPY next-env.d.ts next.config.js tsconfig.json ./

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY public src .next ./

EXPOSE 3000

RUN yarn build --cwd .
      
CMD yarn start
```

This is my Docker-compose File-

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
```

SO when I try to run it using `docker-compose up --build` in my nextjs app it shows this error-

```
 => CACHED [app 2/7] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [app 3/7] COPY next-env.d.ts next.config.js tsconfig.json ./                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [app 4/7] COPY package.json yarn.lock ./                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [app 5/7] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile                                                                                                                                         53.4s
 => [app 6/7] COPY public src .next ./                                                                                                                                                    0.4s 
 => ERROR [app 7/7] RUN yarn build --cwd .                                                                                                                                                0.6s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                         
 > [app 7/7] RUN yarn build --cwd .:                                                                                                                                                           
0.526 yarn run v1.22.19
0.544 warning package.json: No license field
0.569 error Command "build" not found.
0.569 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn build --cwd ." did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Can you help regarding what I am doing wrong?
THanks

Comment: Post your package.json file. Run `yarn build --cwd .` on your local machine (outside of docker) and see if it builds.